Change EF6 auto generated names of navigation properties
I have a .NET 4.8 web application with Entity Framework 6 (EF6).
When scaffolding the database model using "Code First From Database" wizard it automatically generates navigation properties for foreign key relationships.
Now, I have this kind of situation: I have a Customer table that has 2 columns named LastUpdateOperatorId and CreationOperatorId that store in line the Id of the Operator that created the record and then, at every update, it stores the Id of the Operator that edited that row.
It has 2 foreign keys, both pointing to the Operators table, each for every operatorId.
When scaffolding the database model in EF it sets the navigation property names as Operator and Operator1.
I could change it manually but consider that at every schema change, when the model is recreated, it overwrites everything.
I would need a way to make the scaffolding automatically generate an alternative navigation property name like, for example, Creator and Editor.
